# Cannot close overlay menu using JavaScript, if i click on list item

Tags: javascript, menu, overlay

I have these lines of code, and i can't make the overlay menu close when i click on the menu items. Can anyone help ?

```
<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
        <div id="myNav-a" class="overlay-content">
            <a href="#home">Home</a>
            <a href="#projects">Projects</a>
            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            <a href="#about">About</a>
        </div>
    </div>

<span class="span-menu" style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>

<script>
    function openNav() {
        document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
    }

    function closeNav() {
        document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `width`, you could use `display`. Try the code snippet below:

```html
<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <div id="myNav-a" class="overlay-content">
    <a href="#home" onclick="closeNav()">Home</a>
    <a href="#projects" onclick="closeNav()">Projects</a>
    <a href="#contact" onclick="closeNav()">Contact</a>
    <a href="#about" onclick="closeNav()">About</a>
  </div>
</div>

<span class="span-menu" style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>

<script>
  function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.display = "block";
  }

  function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.display = "none";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thk for the answer mate, although my overlay menu does work, in that way that it opens and closed when i click the span, although i want it to close automatically when one of the menu items is clicked, and that is what i cant figure out.

Comment: I see. I updated my answer above. Try running the snippet again. I just added `onclick` attributes to your anchor tags with your `closeNav()` method - i.e. `<a href="#home" onclick="closeNav()">Home</a>`

Comment: Awesome :) Glad it helped